# Piwik: plugin's scripts load before widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, matomo

I am developing a new plugin. When I create jQuery events to bind them with html elements I get an error, it is because the script loads before my widget gets rendered. How can I solve this problem?

I already made a setInterval and stopped it when some element of my widget gets rendered, and all the functionality works great; the problem is that when I click again (on my widget's menu option), the widget reloads but the script stops working.

There must be a piwik way to solve this, but I can't find the solution.

Please, help.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Piwik but you can use jQuery to check when elements and sub-elements have loaded.

Have a look at the jQuery [load event](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

An example given there:

```
$( ".widget" ).load(function() {
    // The widget is loaded so handler for .load() called.
});
```